# MATLAB SSLHandshakeException

Tags: xml, matlab, ssl

I am trying to read an xml document from the internet in MATLAB, however, I get the following error;

Java exception occurred:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable
to find valid certification path to requested target

using the command;

xmlread('https://finds.org.uk/database/images/index/objecttype/COIN/format/xml');

However, the weird thing is that its only happening on Windows-based machines and works in Ubuntu Linux and MacOSX. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think it is a pathname issue.  Make sure you can get to the URL.  Try opening webpage in a browser on a window machine.

Comment: I can access it via a browser on a windows machine as well, so the URL is fine.

Comment: Can you access over the network with Matlab?  The version of matlab and tool-kits will make a difference.  Try reading xml from a file and see if it works.  Then you will know if it is an issue with reading the xml or a network issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the solution from;https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92506-how-can-i-configure-matlab-to-allow-access-to-self-signed-https-servers fixed the issue.

Comment: Looks like older version of Matlab ignored certificate errors, while newer version requires certificate.  So you had a different version of matlab on linux than on window.